# TicTacToe with 2d array

Tags: java

My professor wants this code to print out a Tic-Tac-Toe board, but I'm not entirely sure what to do from here.  This is what I've tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    boolean hasWinnerOrStaleMate = false;

    while (!hasWinnerOrStaleMate) {
        int row;
        int col;
        boolean setLocation = false;
        do {
            row = keyboard.nextInt();
            col = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (board[row][col] == '\u0000') // vacant
            {
                board[row][col] = 'X';
                setLocation = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Occupied Try again");
            }
        } while (!setLocation);

        for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, well, did you at least *try* anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint for you: while you're printing out your array, you should look to print a newline after you've printed out one row.

```
for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
        System.out.print(board[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The rest I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Scanner is the class used by your professor for the acquisition of keyboard characters...

If you enter the input within a loop, you made the game of TIC TAC TOE:)